# Doesn't make sense or I don't understand

Tags: grammaticality

If I don't understand what my friend is trying to say do I say "That doesn't make any sense", or do I say "I don't understand." Should the two phrases be the same or is there a more polite way of answering towards maybe a grownup instead of a friend? Which phrase is more casual and which phrase is more proper?

Comment: You may find [ell.se] helpful

Answer (score 2):

"I don't understand" says that "I" can't figure it out - it puts the cause on you.

"That doesn't make any sense" says that your friend can't figure out how to explain it.

So the first wold be more polite.

There may be times when your friend actually doesn't make sense.  Then you might say, "Could you please explain that again?".

Comment: It doesn't always mean "your friend can't figure out how to explain it".  It might mean "it doesn't make any sense.":  "Hey  the dog doesn't look too good, I think he ate too much." "Well, give him a treat, maybe that will make him feel better." "Huh?! That doesn't make any sense!"